# How to reset viewpager content on Android?

Tags: android, android-viewpager

Please tell me how to reset the content of ViewPager on android.
I tried to call adapter.notifyDataSetChanged() but the adapter doesn't call getItem(position) when I scroll the view. It always returns old child views.

Update: This is my Fragment View. When I reset viewPager data, It used loaded Fragment views. It's just start at the onCreateView instead of Constructor.

```
public class ResultView extends Fragment {
//Declare properties

     //Constructor 
public ResultView(Province province, Calendar calendar) {
    Log.d("xskt", "ResultView constructor");
    this.province = province;
    this.calendar = (Calendar) calendar.clone();
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Log.d("xskt", "ResultView onCreateView");
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.resultview, null);

    //do some thing

    return view;
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried to `setOffscreenPageLimit(1)` forcedly?

Comment: No, I will try this right now. Thanks for you tip

Comment: Also you can try to override `public void destroyItem (ViewGroup container, int position, Object object)` `PageAdapter`'s callback to kill fragment that currently outside of the screen. Hope this will helps)))

Comment: I have tried you recommend but no successful. I updated my question with more details of my case.

Comment: Have you tried that solution? http://stackoverflow.com/a/7287121/1001401

Comment: yes, I did. But the problem was not be solved. I have changed to use FragmentStatePagerAdapter rather than FragmentPagerAdapter, it works. So surprise! Thanks.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

I have changed to use `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` instead of `FragmentPagerAdapter`, the problem is resolved. Hope this helps.

Comment: I've found a page and published it on Google+ on this. If people are interested in why this fixes it...https://plus.google.com/114575746308111414670/posts/XgVFNVMJcYM

Answer (score 2):

**I think the best solution to reload fragments in another fragment is :**

```
@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onResume();
    List<Fragment> fragments = getFragmentManager().getFragments();
    if (fragments != null) {
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction  = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        for (Fragment fragment : fragments) {
            if (fragment instanceof Fragment) {
                fragmentTransaction.remove(fragment);
            }
        }
        fragmentTransaction.commitNowAllowingStateLoss();
    }
}
```

Check for your use case whether `commitNowAllowingStateLoss` or `commitAllowingStateLoss` is necessary.

Answer (score 0):

One method is to use the observer pattern.  The data you are presenting is likely in an sqlite DB (or in stored in memory).  You can set a listener in your fragment that will make the necessary updates to your fragment when the data is changed.

Comment: My fragment view load data from DB base on 2 parameter I put on constructor. Please give me some example codes to do this. Thanks you so much.

Comment: @Patrick I would be glad to see some sample code with observer pattern that refreshes the view pager.

Answer (score 0):

It works if you do the following:

- invalidate the viewPager to invalidate the cache
- call notifyDataSetChanged() to tell the adapter that there have been changes and it has to refresh the Fragments
- override getItemPosition in your FragmentStatePagerAdapter in order to have all of your Fragments refreshed

In your Activity or wherever you want to refresh the data:

```
viewPager.invalidate();
fragmentStatePageAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

In you FragmentStatePageAdapter:

```
@Override
public int getItemPosition(@NotNull Object object) {
    return POSITION_NONE;
}
```