# Remove and add page to FragmentPagerAdapter

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, adapter, fragmentpageradapter

i am using a fragment pager adapter with 5 pages. and im setting the adapter to view pager as below

```
 public class xxx extends FragmentPagerAdapter
    {
        final int PAGE_COUNT_LOGGED_IN = 6;
        final int PAGE_COUNT_LOGGED_OUT = 2;
        TextView oTextView = null;
        LayoutInflater inflater = null;
        PagerTabStrip m_oPageTabStrip = null;
        String m_strTab = null;
        String[] m_strArray = null;     
        Context m_oContext = null;

        /** Constructor of the class */
        public xxxx (Context context, android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager oFragmentManager) 
        {
            super (oFragmentManager);
            m_oContext = context;
        }

        /** This method will be invoked when a page is requested to create */
        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int arg0) 
        {       
            xxxxFragment myFragment = new xxxFragment ();
            Bundle data = new Bundle();
            data.putInt("current_page", arg0+1);
            myFragment.setArguments(data);
            return myFragment;
        }

        /** Returns the number of pages */
        @Override
        public int getCount() 
        {       
            if (Utility.m_bIsLoggedIn == true)
            {
                return PAGE_COUNT_LOGGED_IN;
            }
            else
            {
                return PAGE_COUNT_LOGGED_OUT;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) 
        {
            String strText = " ";

            switch(position)
            {
            case 0:
                strText = getBaseContext().getString(R.string.ccc);
                break;
            case 1:
                strText = getBaseContext().getString(R.string.bbb);
                break;
            case 2:
                strText = getBaseContext().getString(R.string.bbb);
                break;
            case 3:
                strText = getBaseContext().getString(R.string.bbb);
                break;
            case 4:
                strText = getBaseContext().getString(R.string.bbb);
                break;
            case 5:
                strText = getBaseContext().getString(R.string.Sbbb);
                break;
            }

        }
```

and in fragment i create a linear layout individually for each page as below

```
bbb.m_oSharedPage = (LinearLayout) LayoutInflater.from(Utility.m_oService).inflate(R.layout.viewpage, null);
                            iView = Utility._YOURS_SHARED;
                            oCurrentPage = .m_oSharedPage;
```

and im setting the adapter as below

```
m_oPager.setAdapter(m_oPagerAdapter);
```

my question is how can i add and remove the 5th page dynamically...like for some case i need page 5 and some case i need to remove page 5.

Answer (score 5):

I have something that might help, I am not changing the `Fragment`, simply removing and adding it back. This will only change from the last position. In other words, if you had *five* `Fragments` and wanted to remove the *third* one then this will not work. I'm not sure this is the best solution, but here is what I have done:

```
mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
```

Then, as a sample I am using an add and remove `click` method:

```
public void remove(View v) {
    // Change the count to whatever you would like
    mSectionsPagerAdapter.setCount(1);
    // Triggers a redraw of the PageAdapter
    mSectionsPagerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}

public void add(View v) {
    // Change the count back to the initial count
    mSectionsPagerAdapter.setCount(2);
    // Triggers a redraw of the PageAdapter
    mSectionsPagerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

I added a `setCount()` method to my `SectionsPagerAdapter`:

```
public void setCount(int count) {
    this._count = count;
}
```

Changed `getCount()` to and added a default count:

```
private int _count = 2;

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return this._count;
}
```

Here is my full `SectionsPagerAdapter`:

```
public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    private int _count = 2;

    public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
        return super.instantiateItem(container, position);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        switch (position) {
        case 0:
            return new FragmentOne();
        case 1:
            return new FragmentTwo();
        default:
            return null;
        }
    }

    public void setCount(int count) {
        this._count = count;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return this._count;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        switch (position) {
        case 0:
            return getString(R.string.fragment_title_one).toUpperCase(Locale.ENGLISH);
        case 1:
            return getString(R.string.fragment_title_two).toUpperCase(Locale.ENGLISH);
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: hi...thanks for the answer...but i have tried it..the problem is ..when count is changed and notfy adapter is called the page is not sidplayed but the content of the page is displayed when i scrol the present last page...since the adpater has the last page created at the begining

Comment: That's odd, I don't get that same reaction, I am not able to scroll over to the page I have removed.

Comment: no you cant scrol but when you elongate the scroll you can see the contents of that page...you wont see the title and all but just the content

Comment: Your problem - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9061325/fragmentpageradapter-is-not-removing-items-fragments-correctly