# FragmentPagerAdapter in Android

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment

I am new in Android. What is the main use `FragmentPagerAdapter` in Android, Is this same as like `BaseAdapter` ??

Where `FragmentPagerAdapter` is used and how does ??

Comment: Check out the **ViewPager** example. http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/04/android-tutorial-using-the-viewpager.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`FragmentPagerAdapter` is one of the `PagerAdapters` provided by the framework to use it in combination with `ViewPager`. In simple words, it provides the `Fragments` to be displayed as pages of the `ViewPager`.

In the other hand, `BaseAdapter` is the base class for all `Adapters` that will deal with `ListViews`.

Comment: Yes. `FragmentStatePagerAdapter`.

Comment: Can you tell me difference between them ?

Comment: Look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18748107/2029566) answer I gave some time back.

Comment: I see, nice answer but I could not understand "The first Adapter might destroy View hierarchy and re load it when needed, the second Adapter only saves the state of the Fragment and completely destroys it, if the user then comes back to that page, the state is retrieved."

Comment: What don't you understand?

Comment: Nothing sorry, what would be destroyed and on what action and why it destroys

Comment: `FragmentPagerAdapter` might destroy the `View` hierarchy completely (basically all the `Views` on that `Fragment'`s xml) when the user swipes away from it. `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` saves the sate of the `Fragment` and completely destroys the `Fragment`.

Comment: Okay got you any mean to save the state ??

Comment: You are saying "FragmentStatePagerAdapter saves the sate of the Fragment" , what state and any mean to save it ?

Comment: I think you should read the [`FragmentStatePagerAdapter`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentStatePagerAdapter.html) docs.