# Android TabLayout Android Design

Tags: android, android-design-library

I'm trying to get the new TabLayout in the android design library working.

I'm following this post:

http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2015/05/android-design-support-library.html

and the documentation:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/TabLayout.html

And have come up with the following code in my activity but the tablayout isn't showing up when I run the activity.

I tried adding   in the activity layout file, but it says it can't find that xml tag.

```
public class TabActivity extends BaseActivity {

    SectionPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;
    ViewPager mViewPager;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_tab);

        LinearLayout v = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.tabContainer);

        TabLayout tabLayout = new TabLayout(this);
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Tab 1"));
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Tab 2"));
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Tab 3"));

        tabLayout.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(FrameLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 50));

        v.addView(tabLayout);

        mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionPagerAdapter(getFragmentManager());

        mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager);
        mViewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabLayout));

    }

    public class SectionPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

        private String TAG = "SectionPagerAdapter";

        public SectionPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position)
        {
            return new Fragment();
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return 2;
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            Locale l = Locale.getDefault();
            switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    return "test";
                case 1:
                    return "test";
                case 2:
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Added the following to my gradle file

```
 compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.0'
```

Comment: I found this good walk through article..
https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Google-Play-Style-Tabs-using-TabLayout

Comment: I've just published a tutorial on a tabbed ViewPager that features separate back navigation for every tab. This might be interesting for you as well: https://medium.com/@nilan/separate-back-navigation-for-a-tabbed-view-pager-in-android-459859f607e4#.a4cro6flq

Answer (score 90, accepted):

I've just managed to setup new TabLayout, so here are the quick steps to do this (ﾉ◕ヮ◕)ﾉ*:･ﾟ✧

1. Add dependencies inside your build.gradle file:

   ```
   dependencies {
       compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
   }
   ```
2. Add TabLayout inside your layout

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="match_parent"
         android:orientation="vertical">

       <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
           android:id="@+id/toolbar"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"/>

       <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
           android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

       <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
           android:id="@+id/pager"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

   </LinearLayout>
   ```
3. Setup your Activity like this:

   ```
   import android.os.Bundle;
   import android.support.design.widget.TabLayout;
   import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
   import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
   import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
   import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
   import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
   import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;

   public class TabLayoutActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

       @Override
       protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
           super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
           setContentView(R.layout.activity_pull_to_refresh);

           Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
           TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tab_layout);
           ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);

           if (toolbar != null) {
               setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
           }

           viewPager.setAdapter(new SectionPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager()));
           tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
       }

       public class SectionPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

           public SectionPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
               super(fm);
           }

           @Override
           public Fragment getItem(int position) {
               switch (position) {
                   case 0:
                       return new FirstTabFragment();
                   case 1:
                   default:
                       return new SecondTabFragment();
               }
           }

           @Override
           public int getCount() {
               return 2;
           }

           @Override
           public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
               switch (position) {
                   case 0:
                       return "First Tab";
                   case 1:
                   default:
                       return "Second Tab";
               }
           }
       }

   }
   ```

Comment: looks good! is compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:22.2.0' required?  I think I was just missing adding it into my layout.

Comment: @TWilly no, support:recyclerview isn't required. I've removed it from the answer.

Comment: How to add custom fonts in TabLayout??

Comment: @DroidLearner if you want to customize your tabs more than changing text color or icon, you may use setCustomView() method while adding your tabs to the TabLayout widget.
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/TabLayout.Tab.html#setCustomView(android.view.View)

Comment: I'm using the same setup, all is good, when I swipe the pages the tablayout always updates. but when I select a tab the fragment doesn't always update. 30% of the times it stays on the same page. Am I doing something wrong? Or is this a bug as it's new.

Comment: @jasxir I cannot reproduce your issue with the very same setup that is described in my answer. Furthermore I do use this in production and I haven't received any bug reports about tabs behaviour yet. So, double-check your code, and if problem still exists, I'll need to see it (snippet of sample where it can be reproduced) to help you.

Comment: Now I replaced `tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);` with the three things that method should do, adding `OnTabSelectListener` to the `TabLayout`, Populating the tabs from the `PagerAdapter`, and adding `addOnPageChangeListener` on the `ViewPager`. So now it works fine. But as mentioned in the API doc `tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);` does these 3 things, when I do them myself it works fine, but with that one line it seems to be unreliable.

Comment: The way I reproduce it, is by swiping to another page, **2** of **2** in my case. Then clicking the tab to get back to page **1**. Most of the times the tab-indicator slides, but the page remains the same.

Comment: @jasxir well, the setupWithViewPager() method do those 3 thing (you can check the source code), so I do believe you've mistaken somewhere. However, I am not 100% sure it's not the Android bug, because.. well, it's full of bugs.

Comment: Thanks for your example! It's really good. However, I have a question: why do we need the toolbar? Is it required or optional? :)

Comment: @Forte_201092 well, it's absolutely optional, I just needed it for my app :)

Comment: Thanks compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1' solved the problem

Answer (score 2):

I had to collect information from various sources to put together a functioning TabLayout.  The following is presented as a complete use case that can be modified as needed.

Make sure the module `build.gradle` file contains a dependency on `com.android.support:design`.

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
}
```

In my case, I am creating an About activity in the application with a TabLayout.  I added the following section to `AndroidMainifest.xml`.  Setting the parentActivityName allows the home arrow to take the user back to the main activity.

```
<!-- android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize" makes the activity not reload when the orientation changes. -->
<activity
    android:name=".AboutActivity"
    android:label="@string/about_app"
    android:theme="@style/MyApp.About"
    android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity"
    android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize" >

    <!-- android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY is necessary for API <= 15. -->
    <meta-data
        android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
        android:value=".MainActivity" />
</activity>
```

`styles.xml` contains the following entries.  This app has a white AppBar for the main activity and a blue AppBar for the About activity.  We need to set `colorPrimaryDark` for the About activity so that the status bar above the AppBar is blue.

```
<style name="MyApp" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/blue</item>
</style>

<style name="MyApp.About" />

<!-- ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" makes the text and the icons in the AppBar white. -->
<style name="MyApp.DarkAppBar" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />

<style name="MyApp.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar" />

<style name="MyApp.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
```

There is also a `styles.xml (v19)`.  It is located at `src/main/res/values-v19/styles.xml`.  This file is only applied if the API of the device is >= 19.

```
<!-- android:windowTranslucentStatus requires API >= 19.  It makes the system status bar transparent.
  When it is specified the root layout should include android:fitsSystemWindows="true".
  colorPrimaryDark goes behind the status bar, which is then darkened by the overlay. -->
<style name="MyApp.About">
    <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/blue</item>
</style>
```

`AboutActivity.java` contains the following code.  In my case I have a fixed number of tabs (7) so I could remove all the code dealing with dynamic tabs.

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.TabLayout;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;

public class AboutActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.about_coordinatorlayout);

        // We need to use the SupportActionBar from android.support.v7.app.ActionBar until the minimum API is >= 21.
        Toolbar supportAppBar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.about_toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(supportAppBar);

        // Display the home arrow on supportAppBar.
        final ActionBar appBar = getSupportActionBar();
        assert appBar != null;// This assert removes the incorrect warning in Android Studio on the following line that appBar might be null.
        appBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        //  Setup the ViewPager.
        ViewPager aboutViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.about_viewpager);
        assert aboutViewPager != null; // This assert removes the incorrect warning in Android Studio on the following line that aboutViewPager might be null.
        aboutViewPager.setAdapter(new aboutPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager()));

        // Setup the TabLayout and connect it to the ViewPager.
        TabLayout aboutTabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.about_tablayout);
        assert aboutTabLayout != null; // This assert removes the incorrect warning in Android Studio on the following line that aboutTabLayout might be null.
        aboutTabLayout.setupWithViewPager(aboutViewPager);
    }

    public class aboutPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
        public aboutPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        // Get the count of the number of tabs.
        public int getCount() {
            return 7;
        }

        @Override
        // Get the name of each tab.  Tab numbers start at 0.
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int tab) {
            switch (tab) {
                case 0:
                    return getString(R.string.version);

                case 1:
                    return getString(R.string.permissions);

                case 2:
                    return getString(R.string.privacy_policy);

                case 3:
                    return getString(R.string.changelog);

                case 4:
                    return getString(R.string.license);

                case 5:
                    return getString(R.string.contributors);

                case 6:
                    return getString(R.string.links);

                default:
                    return "";
            }
        }

        @Override
        // Setup each tab.
        public Fragment getItem(int tab) {
            return AboutTabFragment.createTab(tab);
        }
    }
}
```

`AboutTabFragment.java` is used to populate each tab.  In my case, the first tab has a `LinearLayout` inside of a `ScrollView` and all the others have a `WebView` as the root layout.

```
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class AboutTabFragment extends Fragment {
    private int tabNumber;

    // AboutTabFragment.createTab stores the tab number in the bundle arguments so it can be referenced from onCreate().
    public static AboutTabFragment createTab(int tab) {
        Bundle thisTabArguments = new Bundle();
        thisTabArguments.putInt("Tab", tab);
        AboutTabFragment thisTab = new AboutTabFragment();
        thisTab.setArguments(thisTabArguments);
        return thisTab;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Store the tab number in tabNumber.
        tabNumber = getArguments().getInt("Tab");
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View tabLayout;

        // Load the about tab layout.  Tab numbers start at 0.
        if (tabNumber == 0) {
            // Setting false at the end of inflater.inflate does not attach the inflated layout as a child of container.
            // The fragment will take care of attaching the root automatically.
            tabLayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.about_tab_version, container, false);
        } else { // load a WebView for all the other tabs.  Tab numbers start at 0.
            // Setting false at the end of inflater.inflate does not attach the inflated layout as a child of container.
            // The fragment will take care of attaching the root automatically.
            tabLayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.about_tab_webview, container, false);
            WebView tabWebView = (WebView) tabLayout;

            switch (tabNumber) {
                case 1:
                tabWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/about_permissions.html");
                    break;

                case 2:
                    tabWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/about_privacy_policy.html");
                    break;

                case 3:
                    tabWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/about_changelog.html");
                    break;

                case 4:
                    tabWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/about_license.html");
                    break;

                case 5:
                    tabWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/about_contributors.html");
                    break;

                case 6:
                    tabWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/about_links.html");
                    break;

                default:
                    break;
            }
        }

        return tabLayout;
    }
}
```

`about_coordinatorlayout.xml` is as follows:

```
<!-- android:fitsSystemWindows="true" moves the AppBar below the status bar.
  When it is specified the theme should include <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
  to make the status bar a transparent, darkened overlay. -->
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:id="@+id/about_coordinatorlayout"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true" >

    <!-- the LinearLayout with orientation="vertical" moves the ViewPager below the AppBarLayout. -->
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <!-- We need to set android:background="@color/blue" here or any space to the right of the TabLayout on large devices will be white. -->
        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/about_appbarlayout"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/blue"
            android:theme="@style/MyApp.AppBarOverlay" >

            <!-- android:theme="@style/PrivacyBrowser.DarkAppBar" makes the text and icons in the AppBar white. -->
            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/about_toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@color/blue"
                android:theme="@style/MyApp.DarkAppBar"
                app:popupTheme="@style/MyApp.PopupOverlay" />

            <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                android:id="@+id/about_tablayout"
                xmlns:android.support.design="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android.support.design:tabBackground="@color/blue"
                android.support.design:tabTextColor="@color/light_blue"
                android.support.design:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/white"
                android.support.design:tabIndicatorColor="@color/white"
                android.support.design:tabMode="scrollable" />
        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

        <!-- android:layout_weight="1" makes about_viewpager fill the rest of the screen. -->
        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/about_viewpager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1" />
    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

`about_tab_version.xml` is as follows:

```
<!-- The ScrollView allows the LinearLayout to scroll if it exceeds the height of the page. -->
<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/about_version_scrollview"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/about_version_linearlayout"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="16dp" >

        <!-- Include whatever content you want in this tab here. -->

    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

And `about_tab_webview.xml`:

```
<!-- This WebView displays inside of the tabs in AboutActivity. -->
<WebView
    android:id="@+id/about_tab_webview"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

There are also entries in `strings.xml`

```
<string name="about_app">About App</string>
<string name="version">Version</string>
<string name="permissions">Permissions</string>
<string name="privacy_policy">Privacy Policy</string>
<string name="changelog">Changelog</string>
<string name="license">License</string>
<string name="contributors">Contributors</string>
<string name="links">Links</string>
```

And `colors.xml`

```
<color name="blue">#FF1976D2</color>
<color name="light_blue">#FFBBDEFB</color>
<color name="white">#FFFFFFFF</color>
```

`src/main/assets` contains the HTML files referenced in `AboutTabFragemnt.java`.

Comment: where do you have the getString method from?

Comment: @RichArt  getString is a public method of the standard Android Context.  https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getString(int)  Depending on where you are writing the code, you may need to use `getResources.getString()`.

Answer (score 2):

I try to solve here is my code.

first add dependency in build.gradle(app).

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
}
```

Create **PagerAdapter.class**

```
public class PagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
    private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

    public PagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager) {
        super(manager);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        Log.i("PosTabItem",""+position);
        return mFragmentList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mFragmentList.size();
    }

    public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title) {
        mFragmentList.add(fragment);
        mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        Log.i("PosTab",""+position);

        return mFragmentTitleList.get(position);
    }
}
```

create activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:elevation="6dp"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:elevation="6dp"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/tab_layout" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

create **MainActivity.class**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Pager pager;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tab_layout);


        final ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
         pager = new Pager(getSupportFragmentManager());

        pager.addFragment(new FragmentOne(), "One");

        viewPager.setAdapter(pager);

        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
        tabLayout.setTabMode(TabLayout.MODE_FIXED);
        tabLayout.setSmoothScrollingEnabled(true);

        viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabLayout));

        tabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
                viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
            }

            @Override
            public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }
        });
    }
}
```

and finally create fragment to add in viewpager

crate fragment_one.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:text="Location"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Create **FragmentOne.class**

```
public class FragmentOne extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_one, container,false);
        return view;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> I am facing some issue with menu change when fragment changes in ViewPager. I ended up implemented below code.

**DashboardFragment**

```
public class DashboardFragment extends BaseFragment {

    private Context mContext;
    private TabLayout mTabLayout;
    private ViewPager mViewPager;
    private DashboardPagerAdapter mAdapter;
    private OnModuleChangeListener onModuleChangeListener;
    private NavDashBoardActivity activityInstance;

    public void setOnModuleChangeListener(OnModuleChangeListener onModuleChangeListener) {
        this.onModuleChangeListener = onModuleChangeListener;
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.dashboard_fragment, container, false);
    }

    //pass -1 if you want to get it via pager
    public Fragment getFragmentFromViewpager(int position) {
        if (position == -1)
            position = mViewPager.getCurrentItem();
        return ((Fragment) (mAdapter.instantiateItem(mViewPager, position)));
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        mContext = getActivity();

        activityInstance = (NavDashBoardActivity) getActivity();

        mTabLayout = (TabLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.tab_layout);
        mViewPager = (ViewPager) view.findViewById(R.id.view_pager);

        final List<EnumUtils.Module> moduleToShow = getModuleToShowList();
        mViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(moduleToShow.size());

        for(EnumUtils.Module module :moduleToShow)
            mTabLayout.addTab(mTabLayout.newTab().setText(EnumUtils.Module.getTabText(module)));

        updateTabPagerAndMenu(0 , moduleToShow);

        mAdapter = new DashboardPagerAdapter(getFragmentManager(),moduleToShow);
        mViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(mAdapter.getCount());

        mViewPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);

        mTabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTabSelected(final TabLayout.Tab tab) {
                    mViewPager.post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        mViewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
                    }
                });
            }

            @Override
            public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
            }
        });

        mViewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {
                //added to redraw menu on scroll
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                updateTabPagerAndMenu(position , moduleToShow);
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {
            }
        });
    }

    //also validate other checks and this method should be in SharedPrefs...
    public static List<EnumUtils.Module> getModuleToShowList(){
        List<EnumUtils.Module> moduleToShow = new ArrayList<>();

        moduleToShow.add(EnumUtils.Module.HOME);
        moduleToShow.add(EnumUtils.Module.ABOUT);

        return moduleToShow;
    }

    public void setCurrentTab(final int position){
        if(mViewPager != null){
            mViewPager.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    mViewPager.setCurrentItem(position);
                }
            },100);
        }
    }

    private Fragment getCurrentFragment(){
        return mAdapter.getCurrentFragment();
    }

    private void updateTabPagerAndMenu(int position , List<EnumUtils.Module> moduleToShow){
        //it helps to change menu on scroll
        //http://stackoverflow.com/a/27984263/3496570
        //No effect after changing below statement
        ActivityCompat.invalidateOptionsMenu(getActivity());
        if(mTabLayout != null)
            mTabLayout.getTabAt(position).select();

        if(onModuleChangeListener != null){

            if(activityInstance != null){
                activityInstance.updateStatusBarColor(
                        EnumUtils.Module.getStatusBarColor(moduleToShow.get(position)));
            }
            onModuleChangeListener.onModuleChanged(moduleToShow.get(position));

            mTabLayout.setSelectedTabIndicatorColor(EnumUtils.Module.getModuleColor(moduleToShow.get(position)));
            mTabLayout.setTabTextColors(ContextCompat.getColor(mContext,android.R.color.black)
                    , EnumUtils.Module.getModuleColor(moduleToShow.get(position)));
        }
    }
}
```

**dashboardfragment.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <!-- our tablayout to display tabs  -->
    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        app:tabBackground="@android:color/white"
        app:tabGravity="fill"
        app:tabIndicatorHeight="4dp"
        app:tabMode="scrollable"
        app:tabSelectedTextColor="@android:color/black"
        app:tabTextColor="@android:color/black" />

    <!-- View pager to swipe views -->
    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/view_pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**DashboardPagerAdapter**

```
public class DashboardPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

private List<EnumUtils.Module> moduleList;
private Fragment mCurrentFragment = null;

public DashboardPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, List<EnumUtils.Module> moduleList){
    super(fm);
    this.moduleList = moduleList;
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    return EnumUtils.Module.getDashboardFragment(moduleList.get(position));
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return moduleList.size();
}

@Override
public void setPrimaryItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
    if (getCurrentFragment() != object) {
        mCurrentFragment = ((Fragment) object);
    }
    super.setPrimaryItem(container, position, object);
}

public Fragment getCurrentFragment() {
    return mCurrentFragment;
}

public int getModulePosition(EnumUtils.Module moduleName){
    for(int x = 0 ; x < moduleList.size() ; x++){
        if(moduleList.get(x).equals(moduleName))
            return x;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

}

And in each page of Fragment `setHasOptionMenu(true)` in **onCreate** and implement `onCreateOptionMenu`. then it will work properly.

dASHaCTIVITY

```
public class NavDashBoardActivity extends BaseActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    private Context mContext;
    private DashboardFragment dashboardFragment;
    private Toolbar mToolbar;
    private DrawerLayout drawer;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_nav_dash_board);

        mContext = NavDashBoardActivity.this;
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);
            getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS);
            getWindow().setStatusBarColor(ContextCompat.getColor(mContext,R.color.yellow_action_bar));
        }

        mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);

        updateToolbarText(new ToolbarTextBO("NCompass " ,""));

        drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, mToolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        //onclick of back button on Navigation it will popUp fragment...
        toggle.setToolbarNavigationClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if(!toggle.isDrawerIndicatorEnabled()) {
                    getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack();
                }
            }
        });

        final NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setItemIconTintList(null);//It helps to show icon on Navigation
        updateNavigationMenuItem(navigationView);

        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

        //Left Drawer Upper Section
        View headerLayout = navigationView.getHeaderView(0); // 0-index header

        TextView userNameTv = (TextView) headerLayout.findViewById(R.id.tv_user_name);
        userNameTv.setText(AuthSharePref.readUserLoggedIn().getFullName());
        RoundedImageView ivUserPic = (RoundedImageView) headerLayout.findViewById(R.id.iv_user_pic);

        ivUserPic.setImageResource(R.drawable.profile_img);

        headerLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                //close drawer and add a fragment to it
                drawer.closeDrawers();//also try other methods..
            }
        });

        //ZA code starts...
        dashboardFragment = new DashboardFragment();
        dashboardFragment.setOnModuleChangeListener(new OnModuleChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onModuleChanged(EnumUtils.Module module) {
                if(mToolbar != null){
                    mToolbar.setBackgroundColor(EnumUtils.Module.getModuleColor(module));

                    if(EnumUtils.Module.getMenuID(module) != -1)
                        navigationView.getMenu().findItem(EnumUtils.Module.getMenuID(module)).setChecked(true);
                }
            }
        });

        addBaseFragment(dashboardFragment);
        backStackListener();
    }



    public void updateStatusBarColor(int colorResourceID){
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);
            getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS);
            getWindow().setStatusBarColor(colorResourceID);
        }
    }

    private void updateNavigationMenuItem(NavigationView navigationView){
        List<EnumUtils.Module> modules =  DashboardFragment.getModuleToShowList();

        if(!modules.contains(EnumUtils.Module.MyStores)){
            navigationView.getMenu().findItem(R.id.nav_my_store).setVisible(false);
        }
        if(!modules.contains(EnumUtils.Module.Livewall)){
            navigationView.getMenu().findItem(R.id.nav_live_wall).setVisible(false);
        }
    }

    private void backStackListener(){
        getSupportFragmentManager().addOnBackStackChangedListener(new FragmentManager.OnBackStackChangedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onBackStackChanged() {

                if(getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() >= 1)
                {
                    toggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(false); //disable "hamburger to arrow" drawable
                    toggle.setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.ic_arrow_back_black_24dp); //set your own
                    ///toggle.setDrawerArrowDrawable();
                    ///toggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(false); // this will hide hamburger image
                    ///Toast.makeText(mContext,"Update to Arrow",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                else{
                    toggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(true);
                }
                if(getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() >0){
                    if(getCurrentFragment() instanceof DashboardFragment){
                        Fragment subFragment = ((DashboardFragment) getCurrentFragment())
                                .getViewpager(-1);
                    }
                }
                else{

                }
            }
        });
    }

    private void updateToolBarTitle(String title){
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle(title);
    }
    public void updateToolBarColor(String hexColor){
        if(mToolbar != null)
            mToolbar.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(hexColor));
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START))
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.empty, menu);

        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);//true is wriiten first..
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == android.R.id.home)
        {
            if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START))
                drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
            else {
                if (getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() > 0) {

                } else
                    drawer.openDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
            }

            return false;///true;
        }

        return false;// false so that fragment can also handle the menu event. Otherwise it is handled their
        ///return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.nav_my_store) {
            // Handle the camera action
            dashboardFragment.setCurrentTab(EnumUtils.Module.MyStores);
        } 
        }else if  (id == R.id.nav_log_out)  {
            Dialogs.logOut(mContext);
        }

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }


    public void updateToolbarText(ToolbarTextBO toolbarTextBO){
        mToolbar.setTitle("");
        mToolbar.setSubtitle("");
        if(toolbarTextBO.getTitle() != null && !toolbarTextBO.getTitle().isEmpty())
            mToolbar.setTitle(toolbarTextBO.getTitle());
        if(toolbarTextBO.getDescription() != null && !toolbarTextBO.getDescription().isEmpty())
            mToolbar.setSubtitle(toolbarTextBO.getDescription());*/

    }

    @Override
    public void onPostCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState, @Nullable PersistableBundle persistentState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState, persistentState);
        // Sync the toggle state after onRestoreInstanceState has occurred.
        toggle.syncState();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        toggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".ui.MainActivity"
    >
    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            android:elevation="6dp"
            android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:tabMode="fixed"
            app:tabGravity="fill"
            >
            <android.support.design.widget.TabItem
                android:id="@+id/tabItem"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/tab_text_1" />

            <android.support.design.widget.TabItem
                android:id="@+id/tabItem2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/tab_text_2" />
            <android.support.design.widget.TabItem
                android:id="@+id/tabItem3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/tab_text_3" />
            <android.support.design.widget.TabItem
                android:id="@+id/tItemab4"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/tab_text_4" />
        </android.support.design.widget.TabLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/tabs"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        tools:ignore="NotSibling"/>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

```css
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ui.MainActivity">
    <include layout="@layout/tabs"></include>
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:layout_marginTop="80dp">
        <FrameLayout android:id="@+id/tabContent"
            android:layout_weight="1" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="0dp">
        </FrameLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

```css
public class MainActivity extends  AppCompatActivity{

  private Toolbar toolbar;
    private TabLayout tabLayout;
    private ViewPagerAdapter adapter;

    private final static int[] tabIcons = {
            R.drawable.ic_action_car,
            android.R.drawable.ic_menu_mapmode,
            android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_email,
            R.drawable.ic_action_settings
    };

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        
            Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
       setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager)         findViewById(R.id.container);
        setupViewPager(viewPager);


        tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
        setupTabIcons();

        
        }
            private void setupTabIcons() {
        tabLayout.getTabAt(0).setIcon(tabIcons[0]);
        tabLayout.getTabAt(1).setIcon(tabIcons[1]);
        tabLayout.getTabAt(2).setIcon(tabIcons[2]);
        tabLayout.getTabAt(3).setIcon(tabIcons[3]);
    }

    private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
        adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        adapter.addFrag(new CarFragment());
        adapter.addFrag(new LocationFragment());
        adapter.addFrag(new MessageFragment());
        adapter.addFrag(new SettingsFragment());
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
    
    class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
        private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
        ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager) {
            super(manager);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            return mFragmentList.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return mFragmentList.size();
        }

        void addFrag(Fragment fragment) {
            mFragmentList.add(fragment);

        }

    }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

So easy way :

XML:

```
<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#fff"/>
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

Java code:

```
private ViewPager viewPager;

private String[] PAGE_TITLES = new String[]{
        "text1",
        "text1",
        "text3"
};
private final Fragment[] PAGES = new Fragment[]{
        new fragment1(), 
        new fragment2(),
        new fragment3()

};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.layout_a_requests);

    /**TODO ***************tebLayout*************************/
    viewPager = findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
    viewPager.setAdapter(new MyPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager()));
    TabLayout tabLayout = findViewById(R.id.tab_layout);
    tabLayout.setSelectedTabIndicatorColor(Color.parseColor("#1f57ff"));
    tabLayout.setSelectedTabIndicatorHeight((int) (4 * 
    getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density));
    tabLayout.setTabTextColors(Color.parseColor("#9d9d9d"), 
    Color.parseColor("#0d0e10"));
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
    /***************************************************************************/
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this to the module build.gradle:

```
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'

implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
```