# Swipe Views with Tabs

Tags: android, tabs, android-viewpager, swipe

I'm trying to make a swipe views with tabs, and I found a lot of examples that works, but, I would like to work with actual elements and not deprecated like:

- actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS)
- actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
- actionBar.addTab(...)

Comment: There are [many libraries for working with `ViewPager`](http://android-arsenal.com/tag/111), including many implementations of tabs.

Comment: have you checked out this tutorial: https://androidbeasts.wordpress.com/2015/08/11/tabs-with-swipe-views/

Comment: @Aakash this tutorial could help, but if the minimumSDK is 19 my app will be less util, thanks anyway

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If switch to the android support library is an option for you then you can use the new TabLayout.

See an example implementation here:
http://blog.grafixartist.com/material-design-tabs-with-android-design-support-library/

If his is not an option you can take a look at the android developer sample called 'SlidingTabsBasic' which provides a tab control.

https://developer.android.com/samples/SlidingTabsBasic/index.html

Comment: First link was perfect to me because Main activity extends from App Compact Activity, but it has things that i don't understand. Nevertheless, the second one is native and simple, Thank you!.

Comment: Sorry, the blog in the first link does more then only add the tabbar. So maybe this answer is what you are looking for : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30539772/android-tablayout-android-design 
 If you still interested.