# Extend Toolbar vertically like Google Maps application

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, material-design, android-toolbar

My goal is to extend the [Toolbar](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/Toolbar.html) vertically and add similar information as shown here (specifically I mean the last row with the **car**, **tram**, **walking**, and **bike** icons and times):

[image: Google Maps screenshot]

I have used `LinearLayout` to add some content in the toolbar's xml file and, indeed, I have managed to have a "row" with a `TextView` and a "row" with a `Button` (tell me if you need to see a screenshot):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#CCC">
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:text="Application Title"/>
        <Button
            android:layout_width="128dp"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:text="A button"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Please, consider that this extended toolbar will be extended only during some activities, it's not going to be like this permanently; most views will use it in its simple form, i.e. just the application title and a menu on the right (which is not yet added in my design).

Am I on the right track or am I missing something? Is there another recommended way to have the same results? Is this how Google implemented it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See this post: [Android TabLayout Android Design](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30539772/2196702)
Especially the link to the[Android Developers Blog](http://android-developers.blogspot.de/2015/05/android-design-support-library.html) in the question. You want to use a Tablayout for the tabs with car, bike etc and an expanding toolbar. Both are described in the blogpost.

Comment: You mean the **Collapsing Toolbar**, but yes this is it! Someone else mentioned this as a comment, but you have posted an answer, so I'll accept this.