# Menu under ActionBar

Tags: android, menu, android-actionbar

I need to make a menu under ActionBar like on the picture ("Movies", "TV Shows")

[image]

Comment: you haven't asked a question yet, you've just listed a requirement, please edit to show what you've tried and what you're struggling with

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is a tabLayout
documentation here :

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/TabLayout

[Android TabLayout Android Design](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30539772/android-tablayout-android-design)

Comment: Today it is better to link the [TabLayout](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/components/TabLayout.md) in the Material Components library.