# Difference between FragmentPagerAdapter with ViewPager with OffScreenLimit set to 1 and FragmentStatePagerAdapter?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-pageradapter

What is the difference between `FragmentPagerAdapter` with ViewPager with OffScreenLimit set to 1 and `FragmentStatePagerAdapter`?

About `FragmentPagerAdapter` Google's guide says:

> This version of the pager is best for use when there are a handful of
>   typically more static fragments to be paged through, such as a set of
>   tabs. The fragment of each page the user visits will be kept in
>   memory, though its view hierarchy may be destroyed when not visible.
>   This can result in using a significant amount of memory since fragment
>   instances can hold on to an arbitrary amount of state. For larger sets
>   of pages, consider FragmentStatePagerAdapter.

And about `FragmentStatePagerAdapter`:

> This version of the pager is more useful when there are a large number
>   of pages, working more like a list view. When pages are not visible to
>   the user, their entire fragment may be destroyed, only keeping the
>   saved state of that fragment. This allows the pager to hold on to much
>   less memory associated with each visited page as compared to
>   FragmentPagerAdapter at the cost of potentially more overhead when
>   switching between pages.

I think if I set the offscreenlimit to 1, it would destroy all fragments outside of the two next of the current fragment, and it behaves similar to a FragmentStatePagerAdapter. Is this correct?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difference between FragmentPagerAdapter and FragmentStatePagerAdapter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18747975/difference-between-fragmentpageradapter-and-fragmentstatepageradapter)

Answer (score 11):

The difference is exactly as it's written in docs. But it can be a little confusing.

`FragmentPagerAdapter` holds its fragments in the `FragmentManager` in detached state while they are not visible (while they are over the offscreen limit bounds) and `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` removes them from the `FragmentManager`.

The `offscreenPageLimit` is something little different. All fragments within it stays attached to the UI. Once they go over, they are either [removed](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentTransaction.html#remove(android.app.Fragment)), or [detached](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentTransaction.html#detach(android.app.Fragment)).

You can see it in sources of [FragmentPagerAdapter](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/master/fragment/java/android/support/v4/app/FragmentPagerAdapter.java#121) (line 121) and [FragmentStatePagerAdapter](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/master/fragment/java/android/support/v4/app/FragmentStatePagerAdapter.java#144) (line 144)