# Why fragment can be nested into Viewpager?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-activity

After reading ViewPager's source code, I got that ViewPager is directly inherited the ViewGroup class,so it's easy to understand View can added to ViewPager.But from Google doc:

> ViewPager is most often used in conjunction with Fragment, which is a
>   convenient way to supply and manage the lifecycle of each page. There
>   are standard adapters implemented for using fragments with the
>   ViewPager, which cover the most common use cases. These are
>   FragmentPagerAdapter and FragmentStatePagerAdapter

We can learn that Fragment can worked with ViewPager.
but the following shows that Fragment is not a View.

> public class Fragment implements ComponentCallbacks,
>   OnCreateContextMenuListener

so my Question is Why fragment can be nested into ViewPager? How does Fragment work with ViewPager? Is possible to use Activity instead of Fragment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Fragment is not a View

True, but you can get the View from `Fragment.getView()`

> Why fragment can be nested into ViewPager

Because `FragmentPagerAdapter` is an Adapter that you attach to a ViewPager to display Fragments

Related:  [Difference between FragmentPagerAdapter and FragmentStatePagerAdapter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18747975/difference-between-fragmentpageradapter-and-fragmentstatepageradapter)

> Is possible to use Activity instead of Fragment?

This is unclear what you want to do, but generally, yes.... Unless you mean load an Activity into a ViewPager, then no. You are supposed to put a ViewPager into an Activity layout, then use the FragmentPagerAdapter to load Fragments into the ViewPager