# issue while hiding a View on ViewPager's fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

am trying to hide and show a View when imageView is being  tapped , i have 3 fragments  in my ViewPager  so the problem is that when am on my first View and i tap the imageView it works fine (my View got hided) but when am on Fragment no. 2 or three and i tap on the imageView it never hides the View its only working on my first fragment , this is my code :

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static int[] imageArray;

    static ImageLoader imageLoader;
    static ArrayList<String> urlArray;
    static DisplayImageOptions options;
    static ProgressBar spinner;

    static PhotoViewAttacher mAttacher;
    static Boolean isToolBarShown = true;

    static Button nextButton , previousButton;

    static ViewPager viewPager ;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        urlArray = new ArrayList<>();

        urlArray.add("http://i.imgur.com/uLRgvM8.png");
        urlArray.add("http://i.imgur.com/LUuJ4FO.png");
        urlArray.add("http://i.imgur.com/7SSBNBA.jpg");


        // Create global configuration and initialize ImageLoader with this config
        DisplayImageOptions defaultOptions = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
                .cacheInMemory(true)
                .imageScaleType(ImageScaleType.EXACTLY)
                .displayer(new FadeInBitmapDisplayer(300)).build();

        ImageLoaderConfiguration config = new ImageLoaderConfiguration.Builder(
                getApplicationContext())
                .defaultDisplayImageOptions(defaultOptions)
                .memoryCache(new WeakMemoryCache()).build();

        ImageLoader.getInstance().init(config);


        imageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance();
        options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder().cacheInMemory(true)
                .cacheOnDisk(true)
                .resetViewBeforeLoading(true).build();

//initialize image view
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);

        ImageFragmentPagerAdapter imageFragmentPagerAdapter = new ImageFragmentPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
         viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);

        viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(1);


        viewPager.setAdapter(imageFragmentPagerAdapter);
    }







    public static class ImageFragmentPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
        public ImageFragmentPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return urlArray.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            //SwipeFragment fragment = new SwipeFragment();
            return SwipeFragment.newInstance(position);
        }

    }

    public static class SwipeFragment extends Fragment {

        private int position;
        private ImageView imageView;
        private RelativeLayout relativeLayout;

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            final View swipeView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.swipe_fragment, container, false);

            imageView = (ImageView) swipeView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
            spinner = (ProgressBar) swipeView.findViewById(R.id.spinner);
            relativeLayout = (RelativeLayout) swipeView.findViewById(R.id.tool_bar);
            Bundle bundle = getArguments();
            nextButton = (Button)swipeView.findViewById(R.id.next_button);
            previousButton = (Button)swipeView.findViewById(R.id.button_previous);

            position = bundle.getInt("position");

            Toast.makeText(getContext(),"NEW PAGE CALLED",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            if (isToolBarShown){

                relativeLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }else {

                relativeLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
            mAttacher = new PhotoViewAttacher(imageView);



//            viewPager.OnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
//                @Override
//                public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {
//
//
//                }
//
//                @Override
//                public void onPageSelected(int position) {
//
//                    loadImageView(position,imageView);
//
//                }
//
//                @Override
//                public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {
//
//                }
//            });

            previousButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    viewPager.setCurrentItem(viewPager.getCurrentItem()-1,true);
                }

            });

            nextButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    viewPager.setCurrentItem(viewPager.getCurrentItem()+1,true);
                }

            });

            return swipeView;
        }





        public void loadImageView(int position, final ImageView imageView ){

            imageLoader.displayImage(urlArray.get(position), imageView, options, new ImageLoadingListener() {
                @Override
                public void onLoadingStarted(String imageUri, View view) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onLoadingFailed(String imageUri, View view, FailReason failReason) {


                    spinner.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }

                @Override
                public void onLoadingComplete(String imageUri, View view, Bitmap loadedImage) {

                     mAttacher = new PhotoViewAttacher(imageView);

                    mAttacher.setOnViewTapListener(new PhotoViewAttacher.OnViewTapListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onViewTap(View view, float x, float y) {

                            if (view == imageView){
                                if (relativeLayout.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE){

                                    isToolBarShown = false;
                                    relativeLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                                }else {

                                    isToolBarShown = true;
                                    relativeLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                }

                                Log.d("OOPS","WHAT THE.., WHAT IS WRONG HERE");
                            }

                        }
                    });


                    if(mAttacher!=null){
                        mAttacher.update();
                    }else{
                        mAttacher = new PhotoViewAttacher(imageView);
                    }


                    spinner.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }

                @Override
                public void onLoadingCancelled(String imageUri, View view) {


                    spinner.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
            }, new ImageLoadingProgressListener() {
                @Override
                public void onProgressUpdate(String imageUri, View view, int current, int total) {

                    spinner.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    spinner.setProgress((current*100)/total);


                }
            });

        }



        static SwipeFragment newInstance(int position) {
            SwipeFragment swipeFragment = new SwipeFragment();
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putInt("position", position);
            swipeFragment.setArguments(bundle);
            return swipeFragment;
        }


        @Override
        public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {
            super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser);
            if (isVisibleToUser) {
                // load data here
//                if (getView() != null) {
//                    isViewShown = true;
//                    // fetchdata() contains logic to show data when page is selected mostly asynctask to fill the data
//                    loadImageView(position , imageView);
//                } else {
//                    isViewShown = false;
//                }
            }
        }





}}
```

am trying to hide and show the `RelativeView` , if anybody knows whats wrong or missing in my code then please do correct me

Comment: Btw question is why in FragmentPagerAdapter in getItem method you are creating SwipeFragment twice by constructor and newInstance static method?

Comment: for getting the position of fragment

Comment: But it seems like you are returning second instance of SwipeFragment. First is created without position.

Comment: so its not necessary ?

Comment: Can you show your SwipeFragment.newInstance method body?

Comment: here you go @MarcinLagowski

Comment: So you should delete first line of getItem method. Its useless.

Comment: `SwipeFragment fragment = new SwipeFragment()` this one ?

Comment: Yes because you are not using this instance of SwipeFragment.

Comment: it makes sense , thanks

Comment: Please tell me where mAttacher is declared is it static variable from outside of SwipeFragment?

Comment: yes you're right @MarcinLagowski

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113377/discussion-between-marcin-lagowski-and-remy-boys).

Answer (score 1):

i think you have to try fragmentstatepageradapter instead of FragmentPagerAdapter. it may help you. you can see the the difference betwwen them here :
    [Difference between FragmentPagerAdapter and FragmentStatePagerAdapter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18747975/difference-between-fragmentpageradapter-and-fragmentstatepageradapter)

Answer (score 1):

You didn't provide all of code, but as you said in comments mAttacher is your static variable from outside of SwipeFragment. I think that

- relativeLayout
- spinner
- imageLoader

are also static members from outside of SwipeFragment. If they are from your `R.layout.swipe_fragment` layout then you should use each relativeLayout, spinner and imageLoader instance per SwipeFragment.

Now you are swiping to another fragment and you see it. But instances of classes i mentioned above are from another fragment. And that is why it does not working for you as it should. Try to do that. And you can provide more of code.

Good luck!

Comment: just added my whole code please take a look and lemme try your suggestion

Comment: As I said you should try to make these instances as variable of SwipeFragment. And you should avoid keeping everything as static variables.

Comment: yeah okay , just because of this static classes i'd to go with the flow

Comment: `public static class SwipeFragment extends Fragment { private int position;
        private ImageView imageView;
        private RelativeLayout relativeLayout;
        private  ProgressBar spinner;` i just created instance in the swipefragment  but still there's a problem since setOffscreenLimit is set to 1 , my next page which is no. 2 is still showing the View even i hided it but my page no.3 is hiding the view and showing the view as expected , the no. 2 is gets loaded before i hide my view on no. 1 , do i have any workaround for this ?

Comment: What happend with mAttacher? where is it declared?

Comment: i declared that too , just now , well things are getting worse now i think i better find another approach well thanks a lot appreciate your effort bro

Answer (score 0):

Setting viewpager offscreenpagelimit mayt help you:)

```
mViewPager.setoffscreenpagelimit(2)
//2 is important over here.
```

Comment: okay i tried this , nothing happened but i wonder what make you think that setting offscreen page limit can help in this matter ??

Answer (score 0):

```
private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title) {
        mFragmentList.add(fragment);
        mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
    }
```

//use above function to set fragment