# Unknown number of fragments: FragmentPagerAdapter or FragmentStatePagerAdapter?

Tags: android, android-viewpager, fragment

In activity I have **`ViewPager`**.
I don't know how many **`fragments`** will be added to **`viewPager`**.

The question is:

What I need to use in this case: **`FragmentPagerAdapter`** or **`FragmentStatePagerAdapter`**?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difference between FragmentPagerAdapter and FragmentStatePagerAdapter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18747975/difference-between-fragmentpageradapter-and-fragmentstatepageradapter)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Surely go with `FragmentStatePagerAdapter`.

`FragmentPagerAdapter` loads all fragments at once and will consume more memory. If you have a lot of fragments, loading all of them at once even may lead to out of memory error.

Even you have known number of fragments, `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` is recommended in most of the cases.