# When I move quickly between tabs and use ViewPager quickly, it crashes

Tags: android, android-fragments

I use `ViewPager` and `Tabs` in my application . When I test the app and move quickly between `tabs` , it crashes . I have one `Fragment` and 3 `tabs` and the content of the `Fragment` change in every `tab` . The content is data from an `API` using `Retrofit 2` . I also use `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` .

here is my `Logs` .

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment MainFragment{423155d0} not attached to Activity
                                                                           at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.getResources(Fragment.java:715)
                                                                           at com.webstore.footballscores.Fragments.MainFragment$4.onResponse(MainFragment.java:393)
                                                                           at retrofit2.ExecutorCallAdapterFactory$ExecutorCallbackCall$1$1.run(ExecutorCallAdapterFactory.java:70)
                                                                           at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
                                                                           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5641)
                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1288)
                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1104)
                                                                           at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

This error in this line

```
    res = getResources();
```

And the rest of code .

```
 connection.enqueue(new Callback<List<FixturesObject>>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<List<FixturesObject>> call, Response<List<FixturesObject>> response) {
            if (!response.isSuccessful()) {
                progressDoalog.dismiss();
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Something went wrong , Please refresh again", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
                    }

                }, 4000);
            } else if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                i=1;
                imageView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                progressDoalog.dismiss();

                    if (isAdded()) {
                 res = getResources();
                String[] teamEngList = res.getStringArray(R.array.team_english);
                String[] teamArabList = res.getStringArray(R.array.team_arabic);
                }

                     if (response.body().get(i).getLeagueId().equals("109")) {

                                for (int j = 0; j < teamEngList.length; j++) {
                                    if (teamEngList[j].equals(response.body().get(i).getMatchAwayteamName())) {
                                        response.body().get(i).setMatchAwayteamName(teamArabList[j]);
                                    } else if (teamEngList[j].equals(response.body().get(i).getMatchHometeamName())) {
                                        response.body().get(i).setMatchHometeamName(teamArabList[j]);
                                    }
                                }
                                spainObject.add(response.body().get(i));
                                listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(listDataHeader.size() - 1), spainObject);
                            }

                   adapter.clearData();

                    adapter.addData(listDataHeader, listDataChild);
                   }
```

How can I fix this error . 
Thanks

Comment: please share your MainFragment code

Comment: My `fragment` has many of lines . Which part you want ?

Comment: at least, the part contains `onResponse(MainFragment.java:393)`

Comment: @PhanVanLinh Done .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are swiping the `ViewPager` is creating fragments for visible pages and destroying for those that are invisible. Your network requests are independent from that process. When a network request finishes and the corresponding fragment is destroyed, you are trying to call `getResources()` but this call requires having a context. A fragment does not have a context anymore if it has been destroyed, thus, you get a crash.

To fix the issue you need to make sure that the context is available before you make that call. Try this:

```
if (!isAdded()) return;

res = getResources();
//...
```

Some documentation: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/Fragment#isAdded()

Comment: Thank you for your answer . When I use `isAdded` and move quickly between tabs , it crashes and give me a `NullPointerException` in `teamEngList []` in this line `for (int j = 0; j < teamEngList.length; j++) {`

Comment: I don't see this code in your original question :) Please update the question and add the whole method. Thanks,

Comment: Should this line be into the condition `isAdded` ?

Comment: Until you post the whole code, I can not tell. Please update the question first. Thanks.

Comment: Updated my answer.

Comment: Yes it works . Thank you I learned a new thing . Also when I add the lines which I added into the condition , It works too .

Answer (score 1):

#### The reason why you get an exception

You are using `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` so `Fragment` in `ViewPager` can be **destroyed** then **detached** ([see my demo here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47522999/5381)).
In each `Fragment`, you run an asynchronous task (using Retrofit) and when it finished you update UI.
If you update UI for a fragment which is destroyed before, you will get the exception

#### Solutions

There are some ways for solving your problem

- Cancel receive the callback from the asynchronous request or cancel the request.
- Before update UI after asynchronous task finished, check if the fragment is [isDetached](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#isDetached()) or not
- Don't let your Fragment destroyed, you can use [setOffscreenPageLimit](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html#setOffscreenPageLimit(int))

Depend on your case, you can choose 1 in 3 ways

Comment: In your answer you explain the lifecycle of each fragment in `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` . I want to tell you an issue and I hope you understand me :) . I have 3 tabs and I use a `ProgressDialog` . So when app start the `ProgressDialog` appear . Now the `fragment 2` has its data . but when I move to it , `ProgressDialog`  appear to load `fragment 3` . my problem is , this `ProgressDialog` is very annoying for user and I can't delete the `ProgressDialog`  . Is there a way to make it better ? I hope you understand my explain .

Answer (score 0):

When the request is completed the fragment has already been detached. Instead of waiting for the response then throwing it away, you could [cancel()](http://square.github.io/retrofit/2.x/retrofit/retrofit2/Call.html#cancel--) the Call, for example.

```
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    connection.cancel();
    super.onDestroy();
}
```

Note that the callback will still be triggered, but with `onFailure()` instead of `onResponse()`