# save state of fragment on tabs

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-tablayout

I have three tabs and each of them uses three different fragments. When I move between the tabs the previous one gets reloaded every time I go back to it.is there a way to pause the current state on the fragment and reuse it when viewed again
.
My tab adapter

```
public class TabAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();
TabAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
    super(fm);
}
@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    return mFragmentList.get(position);
}
public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title) {
    mFragmentList.add(fragment);
    mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
}
@Nullable
@Override
public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
    return mFragmentTitleList.get(position);
}
@Override
public int getCount() {
    return mFragmentList.size();
}
```

and on Main activity

```
adapter = new TabAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
adapter.addFragment(new Daily(), "Daily");
adapter.addFragment(new Trending(), "Popular");
adapter.addFragment(new Random(), "Random");
viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
```

Comment: Check this answer out https://stackoverflow.com/a/17135346/6727154!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create all tab with code

```
viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(3);
```

So they will not be created when you move from tab

Answer (score 0):

In this case you can use `FragmentPagerAdapter` instead of `FragmentStatePagerAdapter`
You can read about that on [Difference between FragmentPagerAdapter and FragmentStatePagerAdapter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18747975/difference-between-fragmentpageradapter-and-fragmentstatepageradapter)