# Is it possible to create app with all Fragments?

Tags: java, android

Is it possible to create and build an app just using Fragment? Even the Sign in and Register?

What is FragmentStatePagerAdapter? Is this required or very helpful when building a app only using Fragments? Thank you for the information. It means a lot to me.

Comment: *Is it possible to create and build an app just using Fragment?* YES **[What is FragmentStatePagerAdapter?](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentStatePagerAdapter)** https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18747975/difference-between-fragmentpageradapter-and-fragmentstatepageradapter

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer. Avoid asking multiple distinct questions at once. See the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: Yes You can using the latest MVP or MVVM architecture

Comment: Ambiguous tag has been removed. `fragment` tag is not recommended for use

Comment: You can build an app with Fragments, but a Fragment is not a view, so they must be contained in some ViewGroup like a FrameLayout for example to be used in one or more activities.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ofcourse yes!!, you can develop an application only using fragments,

> **FragmentStatePagerAdapter** only stores the savedInstanceState of fragments, and destroys all the fragments when they lose focus.

but it is not possible by using  FragmentStatePagerAdapter because it destroys the fragments whenever they are not visible to the user, for that purpose you require something which stores fragments inside the memory and reusable which can be done by using **FragmentPagerAdapter**

Comment: What if all my class is all extended as a fragment and i will create just a Sign in and Register with the Firebase Auth?

Comment: You can create it, you can use firebase Auth also in it!