# ViewPager2 doesn't switch fragments

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, mvvm, android-viewpager

I have an app that uses `NavigationComponents` among with `ViewPager 2`.

I'd like to use `ViewPager` for switching between fragments. I've made my `ActivityMain` as `FragmentContainerView`, and I'd like to have `ViewPager` implemented in one of my fragments.

The problem is, the `ViewPager` doesn't work at all. It doesn't change fragments, don't know why. What should I change in the code?

ActivityMain

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">
    <androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
        android:id="@+id/fragmentContainerView"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/nav_graph" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

First fragment

```
    class BlankFragment : Fragment() {
    private var mPag: ViewPager2? = null


    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_blank, container, false)
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        mPag = view.findViewById(R.id.pager123)
        val adapter = PagerAdapter(this)
        val list = mutableListOf<Fragment>()
        list.add(BlankFragment())
        list.add(BlankFragment2())
        mPag?.adapter = adapter
    }
}
```

.xml

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".BlankFragment"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/test123"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="111111111" />

    <androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2
        android:id="@+id/pager123"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#a1a1"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Second fragment

```
    class BlankFragment2 : Fragment() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

    }
    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_blank2, container, false)
    }
}
```

.xml

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".BlankFragment2">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="222222222222222" />

</FrameLayout>
```

Nav graph

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/nav_graph"
    app:startDestination="@id/blankFragment">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/blankFragment"
        android:name="com.example.myapplication.BlankFragment"
        android:label="fragment_blank"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_blank" />
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/blankFragment2"
        android:name="com.example.myapplication.BlankFragment2"
        android:label="fragment_blank2"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_blank2" />
</navigation>
```

Pager adapter

```
   class PagerAdapter(fragment: Fragment) : FragmentStateAdapter(fragment) {
    val mFragments = mutableListOf<Fragment>()
    
    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return mFragments.size
    }

    override fun createFragment(position: Int): Fragment {
        when (position){
            0 -> return BlankFragment()
            1 -> return BlankFragment2()
        }
        return mFragments[position]
    }
}
```

Comment: I would recommend going through the [get-started](https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/animations/screen-slide-2) of the ViewPager2, also what does the PagerAdapter look like?

Comment: Sorry, forgot to add it. It is in the question now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are essentially missing is what I tried to explain in the previous question.

You need to use `Navigation component` and `ViewPager2` as two separate entities.

There is also issue with your `PagerAdapter`. Fragment adapters are not similar to other Adapters you might have experience with(`mFragments`).
They shouldn't hold a reference to those fragments. There are two main Fragment adapters([more here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18747975/what-is-the-difference-between-fragmentpageradapter-and-fragmentstatepageradapte)).

```
class PagerAdapter(fragment: Fragment) : FragmentStateAdapter(fragment) {

    override fun getItemCount(): Int = 2

    override fun createFragment(position: Int): Fragment {
        return when (position){
            0 -> BlankFragment1()
            1 -> BlankFragment2()
            else -> throw IllegalArgumentException("Out of fragments, will depend on getItemCount")
        }
    }
}
```

You need to have `Fragments` that are solely in the Navigation component(e.g. `FirstFragment` & `SecondFragment`) and `Fragments` that belong to the `ViewPager2`(e.g. `BlankFragment1` & `BlankFragment2`)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation android:id="@+id/nav_graph"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    app:startDestination="@id/FirstFragment">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/FirstFragment"
        android:name="com.example.myapplication.FirstFragment"
        android:label="@string/first_fragment_label"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_first" >
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_FirstFragment_to_SecondFragment"
            app:destination="@id/SecondFragment" />
    </fragment>

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/SecondFragment"
        android:name="com.example.myapplication.SecondFragment"
        android:label="@string/second_fragment_label"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_second" />
</navigation>
```

Fragments for ViewPager2:

```
class BlankFragment1: Fragment() {
    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_blank_1, container, false)
    }
}
class BlankFragment2: Fragment() {
    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_blank_2, container, false)
    }
}
```

The `FirstFragment` is going to host the `ViewPager2` that will allow you to swipe between `BlankFragment1` and `BlankFragment2`.

```
override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
    val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_first, container, false)

    view.findViewById<ViewPager2>(R.id.vp2)?.let { viewPager2 ->
        val pagerAdapter = PagerAdapter(this)
        viewPager2.adapter = pagerAdapter
    }

    return view
}
```

Now the only thing you need to do in any of the fragments to use `Navigation component` is to simply `findNavControler` and `navigate` to `destination` you want.

```
class BlankFragment1: Fragment() {
    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        val view =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_blank_1, container, false)

        view.findViewById<MaterialButton>(R.id.blank_1_button).setOnClickListener {
            findNavController().navigate(R.id.action_FirstFragment_to_SecondFragment)
        }
        return view
    }
}
```